# What's the widget used to assign user permissions in Django admin called?

Tags: django

What's the name of the widget that we use to assign user permission in admin page (under the "add users" option)?

How can I use it for other things?

Answer (score 20):

It sounds like you are talking about `filter_horizontal`.

To use it, add this to your admin config for each model you want to use it:

```
filter_horizontal = ('field1', 'field2',)
```

See [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal).

Comment: @Dominic: Cheers.  
@seema: Don't forget to give this answer a tick if it worked

Comment: Can this filter_horizontal attribute be used in non admin model forms also?